# How to search specific data with lucene.net

Tags: c#, search, lucene.net

often we search db for specific data with sql like

```
select empid,empname,salary from employee where empname ='keith'
OR
select empid,empname,salary from employee where empid =2050
```

here i paste the code which i use to search data with lucene.

```
public static SearchResult BeginSearch(string strSearchTerm, int PageIndex, int PageSize = 10)
    {
        int StartRecPos = 0, TmpEndRecpos = 0, EndRecpos = 0;
        string multiWordPhrase = "";
        multiWordPhrase = strSearchTerm.Replace("*", "").Replace("?", "").Replace("~", "");
        IndexSearcher searcher = null;
        SearchResult list = new SearchResult();
        list.HasData = 0;
        Result oSr = null;
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        if (_directory.FileExists("segments.gen"))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(multiWordPhrase))
            {

                string[] fieldList = { "Title", "Description", "Url" };
                List<BooleanClause.Occur> occurs = new List<BooleanClause.Occur>();
                foreach (string field in fieldList)
                {
                    occurs.Add(BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
                }

                searcher = new IndexSearcher(_directory, false);
                Query qry = MultiFieldQueryParser.Parse(Version.LUCENE_29, multiWordPhrase, fieldList, occurs.ToArray(), new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29));
                TopDocs topDocs = searcher.Search(qry, null, ((PageIndex + 1) * PageSize), Sort.RELEVANCE);
                ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = topDocs.ScoreDocs;
                int resultsCount = topDocs.TotalHits;
                list.HasData = resultsCount;
                StartRecPos = (PageIndex * PageSize) + 1;
                if (topDocs != null)
                {
                    for (int i = (PageIndex * PageSize); i <= (((PageIndex + 1) * PageSize) - 1) && i < topDocs.ScoreDocs.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Document doc = searcher.Doc(topDocs.ScoreDocs[i].doc);
                        oSr = new Result();
                        oSr.ID = doc.Get("ID");
                        oSr.Title = doc.Get("Title");
                        oSr.Description = doc.Get("Description");
                        //oSr.WordCount = AllExtension.WordCount(oSr.Description, WordExist(oSr.Title, multiWordPhrase));
                        string preview =
                        oSr.Description = BBAReman.AllExtension.HighlightKeywords(oSr.Description, multiWordPhrase);  //sr.Description;
                        oSr.Url = doc.Get("Url");
                        TmpEndRecpos++;
                        list.Result.Add(oSr);
                    }
                }

                if (StartRecPos > 1)
                {
                    EndRecpos = (TmpEndRecpos + StartRecPos) - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    EndRecpos = TmpEndRecpos;
                }

                stopWatch.Stop();
                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);

                PageSize = (resultsCount < PageSize ? resultsCount : PageSize);
                list.Pager = SimplePager.GetLinks(PageIndex + 1, resultsCount, PageSize, "Search.aspx?Page={0}&SearchTerm=" + strSearchTerm, "pagerSC", new ResultStatus((PageIndex), PageSize, resultsCount, elapsedTime, StartRecPos, EndRecpos));
                searcher.Close();
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

   private static Query parseQuery(string searchQuery, QueryParser parser)
   {
           Query query;
           try
           {
               query = parser.Parse(searchQuery.Trim());
           }
           catch (ParseException)
           {
               query = parser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(searchQuery.Trim()));
           }
           return query;
    }
```

now my question is how could i include employeeid or employeename in my lucene search when using `MultiFieldQueryParser` ??

i search goole and found some hints that do i need to use `TermQuery query = new TermQuery(new Term("keywords", "info"));`

### a generic code for specific search

```
public void UserSpecificSearch() throws Exception { 
    TermQuery query = new TermQuery(new Term("keywords", "info"));     

    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory); 
    TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, 10);                         
    assertEquals("Both documents match", 2, hits.totalHits);           

    Filter jakeFilter = new QueryWrapperFilter(                        
      new TermQuery(new Term("owner", "jake")));                       

    hits = searcher.search(query, jakeFilter, 10); 
    assertEquals(1, hits.totalHits);                                   
    assertEquals("elwood is safe",                                     
                 "jake's sensitive info",                              
        searcher.doc(hits.scoreDocs[0].doc).get("keywords"));          
  }
```

just tell me the above code is right ? which can help me to search data for specific user or employeeid ??

please guide me what i need to modify in my BeginSearch routine which enable me to search data for specific user. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790795/conditional-search-with-lucene-net?rq=1