# Create a subquery with Lucene.net search

Tags: c#, asp.net, lucene, lucene.net

In order to get the desired results for a Lucene search it is necessary to run something like the following SQL:

```
 Select * from <table> WHERE <field> = <value> AND (<field1> = <value1> OR <field2> = value2>)
```

Is this possible in Lucene?

Thanks

Comment: try BooleanQuery... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790795/conditional-search-with-lucene-net

Comment: I'm using a boolean query. I can't just add the all the clauses in to the query or i end up with wrong data.

Comment: I got one more.. https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/de/d1b/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_wildcard_query.html. This is wild card query documentation.. maybe this can help you.

Comment: Thanks Varun, after some tweaking, I think your first comment might have lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks..glad you solved it..